# WPF Dispatcher slow in performance from commandline

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I have a WPF application which is a calling `Dispatcher.invoke()` on start up.

Problem arise when I start application by double clicking it `Dispatcher.invoke()` takes 1 second to execute but when I start the application from command line it is taking more than 9 seconds to finish the first time. This is independent of what I have written in `Dispatcher.invoke()` method.

I have observed this behavior is for first call to `Dispatcher.invoke()` from command line.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are starting it from the command line?  Doesn't sound like there's any difference in how it would be executed unless I am misunderstanding something.